# My Model Becomes Very Bad When I Tried To Bevel It

Tags: modeling, bevel

I'm making this for my YouTube intro. I was trying to make a glossy texture but then someone said to bevel it so the glossy texture will be better. I tried to bevel it but then it becomes something like this
[image: broken mesh]

Before, it was like this
[image: condition before i bevel it].

Comment: maybe try less segments. Also, some faces may overlap so you'll have to fix it in Edit mode

Comment: You cannot expect for bevel to magically know what you want, you need to set it up better, try different settings, less segments maybe, clean topo (that weird topo above right eyebrow is probably due to bad topo or double vert or something...) top of those hairs well... you must try it different and clean it in edit mode afterwards